# Regex - optional suffix triggered by dash

Tags: c#, regex

I have a simple format that I'm already validating, but want to allow the users to validate that format, but have an optional dash + whatever they want at the end while still validating the first part. I want the dash to be a trigger that tells the Regex that it can accept whatever comes after.

So if my existing regex is something like:

^\d{7}

then I want to be able to update my regex to pass these:

- 1234567-Covid19
- 1234567-Scenario
- 1234567-AnyString

but not these since they are missing the dash:

- 12345678
- 1234567*AnyString
- 1245567AnyString

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can add an optional part `^\d{7}(?:-.*)?$` https://regex101.com/r/RhA6nH/1 Or if you want to accept only 1 or more word characters `^\d{7}(?:-\w+)?$`

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around with a regex tester a bit and came up with the below to satisfy my initial question:

^\d{7}**(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,10})?**

This optionally matches a dash + 1-10 additional alphanumeric characters.